Motion tracking in Blender: Did motion tracking for a sun object but I can't select multiple tracks to join them
I tried motion tracking in blender for the first time today and I was creating a space scene and wanted to add a lens flare effect to the sun. So I was watching a tutorial and did the motion tracking that the tutorial said to do, but my animation has the sun disappear and then reappear later in the animation. So I had to join the newly created tracks. I'm trying to shift select the tracks but blender is not letting me click on the second track while shift clicking. Was hoping someone could help me with this?
Btw I'm running Blender 4.2
Thanks

